# how copy_file function is implemented which is used in CP command

Tags: linux, glibc, cp, file-copying

I am looking at the implementation of copy command from the link :
http://src.gnu-darwin.org/src/bin/cp/cp.c.html
And its using copy_file function  at its core.
if (copy_file(curr, dne))
badcp = rval = 1;

Can someone tell me how copy_file  is implemented or any link to its implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the file where it's implemented:
http://src.gnu-darwin.org/src/bin/cp/utils.c.html